# LINQ To Xml how to generate xml without formatting

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there way to generate xml using linq to xml without any formatting (whitespaces, newlines etc.) and without saving to file, just in memory?

I am sending this xml to some api, and this is requirements. Now i am using `string.Replace();`

```
var doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
            new XElement("request",
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                new XElement("m",
                    new XElement("id", credentials.id),
                    new XElement("signature"), ""),
                new XElement("data",
                    new XElement("p",
                        new XAttribute("id", ""),
                        new XElement("porp",
                            new XAttribute("name", "c"),
                            new XAttribute("value", c)),
                        new XElement("porp",
                            new XAttribute("name", "a"),
                            new XAttribute("value", a))))));


        var data = doc.Element("request").Element("data").Elements();
        string result = string.Concat(data).Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("  ", "");
        var signature = Utils.ComputeSignature(result, credentials.Password);
        doc.Element("request").Element("m").Element("signature").Value = signature;
        return doc.ToString().Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("  ", "");
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this, but the easiest is to use the overload for [`XNode.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551415(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can specify your `SaveOptions`:

```
doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: Thx for your coment. I will use it in return whole document. But is there way to use it in concat?

Comment: Not exactly, you should project your sequence of elements to a sequence of strings: `...Elements().Select(x => x.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting))`.

Comment: @StasPetrov Since it's a method of a base `XNode` class, you can use it inside the concat like `string result = string.Concat(data.Select(e => e.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)));`